# Renaming FB page

Tags: rename, facebook-page

I know it's not allowed after 200 fans but I really need facebook to make an exception... because I'm special?  Ha!  I've renamed my business/brand and hate to start a brand new page with 0 fans.  I've got over 6,000 now.  The content is the exact same, just a simple name change.  My Yellow Sandbox to Twist Me Pretty.

I tried just renaming the URL.  Obviously that didn't work.  I'll have to change it to something else if I do start a brand new page.  Anyway.  I had a friend who said she got special permission to rename her page.  I'm not sure if that was forever ago or if these are new policies.  I'd really love though for my blog name to match my facebook page.  It's bad for business if it doesn't.

Comment: You might get a better response if you ask at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and I searched and searched but couldn't find a way to do this.

Also, it seems Facebook make it as difficult as possible to get in contact with them unfortunately.